# Creating Excel files directly on blob

Tags: azure-blob-storage, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have following function which works fine when saving to disk. I am executing the code from an Azure function. Is there anyway to to write to a blob storage instead without saving to disk?

```
private void ExportDataSet(DataTable ds, string destination)
{
    using (var workbook = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(destination, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
    {
        var workbookPart = workbook.AddWorkbookPart();

        workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Workbook();

        workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets();

        var sheetPart = workbook.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
        var sheetData = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.SheetData();
        sheetPart.Worksheet = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Worksheet(sheetData);

        DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets sheets = workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets>();
        string relationshipId = workbook.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(sheetPart);

        uint sheetId = 1;
        if (sheets.Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet>().Count() > 0)
        {
            sheetId =
                sheets.Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet>().Select(s => s.SheetId.Value).Max() + 1;
        }

        DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet sheet = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet() { Id = relationshipId, SheetId = sheetId, Name = "Sites" };
        sheets.Append(sheet);

        DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row headerRow = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row();

        List<String> columns = new List<string>();
        foreach (System.Data.DataColumn column in ds.Columns)
        {
            columns.Add(column.ColumnName);

            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell cell = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell();
            cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String;
            cell.CellValue = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(column.ColumnName);
            headerRow.AppendChild(cell);
        }   

        sheetData.AppendChild(headerRow);

        foreach (System.Data.DataRow dsrow in ds.Rows)
        {
            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row newRow = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row();
            foreach (String col in columns)
            {
                DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell cell = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell();
                cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String;
                cell.CellValue = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(dsrow[col].ToString()); //
                newRow.AppendChild(cell);
            }    
            sheetData.AppendChild(newRow);
        }                
    }
}
```

I would expect you maybe could save to a Stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save to stream is the solution if you don't like to save it to a disk(In azure function, you can save it to a disk in azure function kudu like D:\home etc.).

If you choose to save to stream, just a few changes to your code, like below:

```
    private void ExportDataSet(DataTable ds, MemoryStream memoryStream)
    {
        using (var workbook = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(memoryStream, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
        {
        //your code logic here    

        }

        //here, the code to upload to azure blob storage.
         CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey), true);    
         CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
         CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("test1");
         CloudBlockBlob myblob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("myexcel.xlsx");


          //upload to blob storage
          memoryStream.Position = 0;
          myblob.UploadFromStream(memoryStream)

          //or you can use Asnyc mehtod like myblob.UploadFromStreamAsync(memoryStream)

    }
```

Note: if you're using the latest azure blob storage sdk [Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob, version 9.4.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob) or later, you can use either `UploadFromStreamAsync` or `UploadFromStream` method in azure function v2.

Comment: Could you explain what the `memoryStream.Position = 0` does? This saved me because without this line, the file will be zero bytes at the storage container. But I would like to understand it better

Comment: @luizs81, because the memoryStream is used(like read operation) previously, then next time when you use it, it will not start from the beginning of the stream. That causes the problem. To solve it, we need to set the position to 0. Please upvote this answer if it's helpful:).